# divs wont fit together properly

Tags: html, css

i cant get the divs to line up properly, they either jump out of the container or they overlap each other, i want the 3 divs spaced equally in the container but it wont work, each div is named accordingly to position and i have played around with clear and float settings but it just wont go

HTML :

```
 <div class="triplecontainer">

<div class="leftbox">
<p> LEFT </p>
</div>


<div class="middlebox">
<P> MIDDLE </P>
</div>


<div class"rightbox">
<P> RIGHT</P>
</div>



</div>
```

CSS:

```
.triplecontainer {
height: 200px;
width: 950px;   
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
margin-top:10px;

}

.leftbox {
height: 180px;
width: 250px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
clear: none;
float: left;

}

.middlebox {
height: 180px;
width: 250px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
float:none;
clear:left

}

.rightbox {
height: 180px;
width: 250px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
float:none;
clear:both;

}
```

Comment: You're clearing floats when you shouldn't, and you're setting float:none when you want float:left.

Comment: You've randomly tried so many things that you've ended up with nonsense.

Comment: You are missing a `=` in your html: `<div class="rightbox">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
display: inline-block;
```

Add to all.  That is what you are missing, you may still need to tweak pixel widths.  Also, you have

```
clear: both;
```

Remove this! In fact, remove all clear commands.

Comment: Just an additional comment, if your user has compatibility mode set on IE11 for example; inline-block wouldn't work back on like IE7 and your divs will just line up vertically.... so for the sake of backwards degredation you might consider adding `zoom:1;*display:inline;` as well so your alignments dont break for older IE versions and compatibility mode consideration. Cheers

Comment: this worked... how would i go about adding the zoom 1 aswell?

Comment: Continuing to support IE7 is pointless, especially now that Windows have dropped support for Windows XP. Using `inline-block` you'll have to be careful of any spaces between each of your elements (as your elements are now inline, `...</div> <div>...` is not the same as `...</div><div>...`). You won't have this problem if you use the table layout my answer below uses, and my answer works on IE8 upwards.

Comment: @SN1Dan - Just literally copy/paste this where you're using display: inline-block; `zoom:1;*display:inline;` as it's only a consideration for older browsers and people using compatibility mode in new versions of IE. As an example, with your new fixed version provided by the answer from @jschavey open it in IE10/11 and add it to the "Compatibility View" available in the options. Without it your horizontal aligned divs will display vertically which you dont want. Cheers

Comment: If this worked, please feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I'm going to assume you don't do much enterpise dev then by that comment....there's still tons of companies that will require users to initiate Compatibility View when using legacy systems still being used and/or other functionality requiring it that they havent caught up with yet.....

Comment: @ChrisW. actually one of the companies I work for is a local government council who in the past month have decided to drop IE7 support from their website thanks to Microsoft no longer supporting XP. OP specified nothing about having to support IE7, so I think my comment here is perfectly valid. This particular solution is okay, but when dealing with 3 fixed-size blocks you may as well use a table layout as this handles everything for you.

Comment: @ChrisW.: Your comments do not make sense. Compatibility View would only be forced for the *specific* broken site (legacy system). It would not be forced for every single site on the internet, because that would make it as if the user had IE7 instead of IE11.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Try a larger company than a local government.

Comment: @thirtydot Absolutely correct, unless they're in IE10 and applying it to everything...personally I try to accomodate such things especially when it literally takes a couple seconds and a couple lines (which dont hurt anything by being there do they?) to do it.

Comment: @ChrisW.: IE7 has like 0.1% of the market or something. Dead browser. I never recommend anything to do with IE7 unless it's specifically mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a fixed table display instead:

```css
.triplecontainer {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.triplecontainer > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5LUUe/).